# MS Outlook 2010 .SenderEmailAddress returns a huge string of characters

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I've searched and searched for an answer so I'll post this here.  I'm trying to create a macro that will move 2 week old messages from my inbox to a specific folder I created for each of my coworkers.  The macro successfully loops though all inbox message older than two weeks.  However, when I use the `.SenderEmailAddress` it retuns a huge string of characters instead of ###@####.com.  How do I just get the senders email address?

Without giving the exact string (security issue), here is what I get with "X"'s in place of some characters:

```
/o=XXXXXXX/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)/cn=Recipients/cn=XXXXX@XXXXX
```

At the end of the string is the Subject line text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: add the relevant part of the code you already have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid EX type address (as opposed to SMTP).

Try to use MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.

You will need to check for nulls/errors of course in case the sender is not an Exchange user or if the address cannot be retrieved.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Figured it was something like that.  I appreciate it!

Comment: This is why I love SE!

Comment: Edit: for people reading this, I get errors on some emails so I check if MailItem.SenderEmailAddress begins with "/O=EXCHANGE" before attempting to retrieve Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.

Comment: Don't check the prefix, check the AddressEntry.Type property - it will be "EX" for GAL entries and "SMTP" for the one-off  SMTP address entries.

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN documentation will [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695.aspx).