# email.SenderEmailAddress for Outlook in C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I'm going to keep this brief as I'm sure you have better things to do than to sit around and read my essay as to why my problem arises.

In short, I've made a Microsoft Outlook addin that among many other functionalities retrieves the email address of the selected email in Outlook. It does this by:

```
var address = email.SenderEmailAddress;
```

Now this works **MOST** of the time, giving me a nice `"asd@asd.asd"` as my `address` variable.

But when the stars align it sometimes gives some of my users something like:

`/O=DOMAINNAME/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHI43SPCLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=JOE BLOGGS8C3`

Now I'm scared by the word `EXCHANGE` because this beastly word hints at use of Microsoft Exchange Sever 20XX (or so I'm guessing?).

If such is the case, how can I retrieve the sender's email?

I google'd around a little and found a few solutions using `VB`, but I don't have any idea how that works, and barely understand enough `C#` to be doing what I'm doing, so I'd appreciate a little newbie-friendly advise on the matter and preferably within the reach of `C#`.

Answer (score 3):

For those in wonder, I did eventually solve my little issue.

I refer to: [MS Outlook 2010 .SenderEmailAddress returns a huge string of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945487/ms-outlook-2010-senderemailaddress-returns-a-huge-string-of-characters)

Specifically:

```
email.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

If anyone has a more thorough explanation to add they can feel free to do so.